# Url of Imagepath not found

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms, image-uploading

I am making a recipe website for a university project, and am writing an upload page so that people can upload their own recipe's, one of the options allows them to upload an image to go with the recipe.

I have managed to make the actual upload work, and to insert an imagepath into my database.
The problem arises when I try and print out the image, i get a 404 error telling me the image cannot be found, although I don't understand this as I can navigate to the image in my browser.

Here is the code from the upload page

```
<?php
require_once ("checklog.php");
require_once ("function.php");
include_once ("home_start_logged.php");
require_once ("db_connect.php");
require_once ("cuisine_dropdown.php");

session_start();

//get form data//
$upload = trim($_POST['Upload']);
$mealname = trim($_POST['mealname']);
$ingredients = trim($_POST['ingredients']);
$hours = trim($_POST['hours']);
$minutes = trim($_POST['minutes']);
$recipe = trim($_POST['recipe']);
$userid = trim($_SESSION['userid']);
$cuisine = trim($_POST['cuisine']);
$meal = trim($_POST['meal']);
$feeds = trim($_POST['feeds']);
$dropoption = trim($_POST['dropoption']);
if(trim($_POST['Submit']) =="Upload"){

        //handle submitted data here
//process details here// 
    if($db_server){
        //clean the input now we have a db connection//
        $mealname = clean_string($db_server, $mealname);
        $ingredients = clean_string($db_server, $ingredients);
        $hour = clean_string($db_server, $hour);
        $minutes = clean_string($db_server, $minutes);
        $recipe = clean_string($db_server, $recipe);
        $ingredients = clean_string($db_server, $ingredients);
        $userid = clean_string($db_server, $userid);
        $cuisine = clean_string($db_server, $cuisine);
        $meal = clean_string($db_server,$meal);
        $feeds = clean_string($db_server,$feeds);
        $dropoption = clean_string($db_server, $dropoption);
        mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) ;

        //check whether the recipe exists//
        $query="SELECT mealname FROM `recipename` WHERE mealname='$mealname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $message = "Meal already exists. Please try again.";
        }else{                                                      
                                //code to process image here//
                                //put file properties into variable//
                                if($_FILES) {
                                $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                                $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
                                $tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                                //determine file type//
                                switch($_FILES['image']['type']){
                                    case'image/jpeg':       $ext ="jpg";    break;
                                    case'image/png':        $ext ="png";    break;
                                    default:                $ext ='';       break;
                                }
                                if($ext){
                                    if($size >30000){
                                            $n="$name";
                                            $n= ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]","",$n);
                                            $n= strtolower($n);
                                            $n="/uploaded_images/$n";
                                            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$n);
                                            echo "<p>Uploaded image'$name' as '$n':</p>";
                                            echo "<img src='$n'/>";
                                    }
                                    else echo "<p>'$name' is too big - 3MB Max(30,000bytes).</p>";
                                }
                                else echo "<p>'$name' is an invalid file - only jpg and png accepted.</p>";
                                }
                                    else echo "<p>No image uploaded. </p>";
                                                                if($cuisine=="") {
                                                                    $query = "INSERT INTO `recipename` (mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userid,b_l_d,feeds,cuisine_type) VALUES ('$mealname', '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe','$n','$userid','$meal','$feeds','$dropoption')"; 
                                                                    mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                                                                    die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ;
                                                                    }else{
                                                                            $query = "INSERT INTO`recipename`(mealname,ingredients,hours,minutes,recipe,imagepath,userid,b_l_d,feeds,cuisine_type)VALUES('$mealname', '$ingredients','$hours','$minutes','$recipe','$n','$userid','$meal','$feeds','$cuisine')";
                                                                            mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                                                                            die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ; 
                                                                            $query = "INSERT INTO `Nation` (cuisine_type) VALUES ('$cuisine')";
                                                                            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                                                                            mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or
                                                                            die("Insert failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server)) ; 
                                                                }
                                        }   
                                        $message = "<strong>Recipe Uploaded!</strong>";             
                                    }
                                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                                }


?>
```

EDIT here is the code to print out:

```
if (!$db_server){
    die("unable to Connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_error($db_server));
    $db_status = "not connected"; 

}else{
    if(trim($_POST['submit']) =="submit"){

    }else{

        if (isset($_POST['dropoption']) && ($_POST['dropoption'] != '')){
            if (isset($_POST['meal']) && ($_POST['meal'] != '')) {

            $dropoption = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['dropoption']);
            $meal = clean_string($db_server, $_POST['meal']);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `recipename` WHERE `cuisine_type` ='$dropoption' AND b_l_d ='$meal'LIMIT 0,1";
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
            $result=mysqli_query($db_server, $query);

            if (!$result) die("database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $recipename .="<h1>". "Why dont you have ".$row['mealname']."</h1>";
                $ingredients .="<p>".$row['ingredients']."</p>";
                $recipe .="<p>" .$row['recipe']."</p>";
                $cookingtime .="<h4>" .$row['hours']." Hours".$row['minutes']." Minutes </h4>";
                $mealpic .="<img src=".$row['imagepath']."/>"; 
                }


<body>
        <?php echo $recipename;
        echo $mealpic;
        ?>

                <h2>Ingredients</h2>
         <?php      
                $ingredientchunks = (explode(",",$ingredients));
                for($i = 1; $i < count($ingredientchunks); $i++){
                    echo "$i.$ingredientchunks[$i] <br/>";}
                echo $cookingtime;
                ?>
                <h2>Recipe</h2>
         <?php
                $recipechunks = (explode(",",$recipe));
                for($i = 1; $i < count($recipechunks); $i++){
                    echo "$i.$recipechunks[$i] </br>";} 
         ?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are moving the image to /uploaded_images/ folder and displaying from /. Is your /uploaded_images setup to be document root? Or maybe you should try to set the img src to /uploaded_images/$n ?

Comment: that folder is where the images are but im not sure how i would set that up?

Comment: You may want to first understand how to specify the correct relative path. Where is the image file located from where your php script is? Unless your php file sits in /uploaded_images you would need to specify the folder in relative to the php script.  Put that relative folder path into the $n before you write to DB

Comment: the uploaded images folder is in the same folder as the php file and the images are within that so in order make the folder path relative would i have to do //uploaded_images/$n?

Comment: Whats in your move_uploaded_file function?

Comment: im not sure I jut used it following instructions?

Comment: give output for this:  ls /uploaded_images/

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this I had to change the output on the results page to:

```
$mealpic .="<img src='http://ml11maj.icsnewmedia.net/Workshops/Week%207/".$row['imagepath']."'/>";
```

from

```
 $mealpic .="<img src=".$row['imagepath']."/>";
```

Comment: That is absolute path, glad that it works in the end.  You may want to spend some time to figure out how to specify file path in HTML.